# Mounting a workspace on external volume via REST API

Tags: eclipse-che

I am trying to create a new workspace in eclipse-che and I wish to mount an external NFS volume in the workspace container.

Can anyone point me to the API where I can give a workspace mount path ?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no API for that, but you may grab host and port of a running workspace and then mount a volume.

Comment: Unfiortunately each workspace is a docker container, and once a container starts, I cannot mount a volume inside the container.

Comment: You can ssh into a container, so use of sshfs tools is possible

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for ["Swagger"](https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/assemblies/sdk-rest-apis/#browsing-rest-apis) browse to `<che-address>:<port>/swagger`.

Once you're at this page go to, "Workspace" -> "get workspace users can read" -> "try it out!".  The response body has a lot of JSON. I recommend ctrl+f for your workspace name eg: "wksp-foo".  About 10 lines above your name you will see the key "id" with a 25 character alphanumeric string that starts with "worksp...".